# After defeating Logan can you be "all good" and win?

Tags: fable-3

After you defeat Logan, the next few (eight or so) good choices leave you with no money in the treasury for the coming war.  Can you still win?  I'd hate to invest a lot of time and still lose.

Comment: The Zero Punctuation review implied that you can let real life time pass and collect money from your properties. Why not just wait until you have sufficiently restocked the treasury?

Comment: And furthermore, I believe I remember reading somewhere that the idea behind fable 3 was that you *couldn't* be all good and win. But, what do I know? I don't own the game. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can still win the game if you go into the final choice with $0 in the treasury and by making all good decisions.

The amount of money you have in the treasury before your final choices only relates to how many people survive the war. You can transfer any money earned personally from your account to the treasury as well before making your final decisions.

Answer (score 1):

8.3 million in your personal account is what you want to shoot for when doing this.  Start buying property as soon as you can with rent at low (not lowest) if you would like to maintain a positive morality through the whole game.  On shops I would leave the income the same, but renting houses and lowering the rent will still do it just fine, as long as you buy up what you can as soon as you enter a town with buildings that are purchasable (some have no income such as the castle and the fort).  Just remember to have that amount before you start making any royal decisions.  Donate all of it, a million at a time right after you become king and it will be fine.  Also if you are worried that you don't have any more money, give it at least five minutes and you will be fine - the income that you have will be enough to do what ever you want. This will give you enough money to save everyone and make good choices.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE kflow - in your next answer it would be great if you could use normal sentence capitalisation to make your answer more readable!

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Started a game, got to this point and realized I didn't have enough money for all the good choices so I restarted the game and made sure to bank at least 8.3 million gold before getting to that point. IIRC I did this by rent as mentioned, and by doing the random jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can make all good decisions and still have enough money in the treasury for everyone to survive the war ... in addition to simply waiting for real-life time to pass, as Raven mentions, you can do other quests in between your assigned tasks. There is nothing that says that you must proceed directly from task 1 to task N and then war.

The best time to do "other stuff" is before the last task on a given day. Once you complete that task, the game will advance to the next day. (I think there are one or two places within a day where one task immediately follows another, but I haven't finished it recently and can't be sure.)

Regardless of how you get money from other quests, as in Blake's answer, you can transfer some of your personal money to the treasury if needed. The key is to spend enough time doing other things to build up enough total money to make good decisions and lose no citizens, if that is what you want to do.

Comment: The trick is knowing when the last day is.  I had a sweet setup, but I miss-gauged when the last say was.  I guess I should have checked out a wiki page, but I like to play though cheat free at least once.

Comment: This is true. I did what most people probably did on my first playthrough - just went straight through without doing too much to build the treasury - and was caught by surprise. The second playthrough, I delayed as much as I could stand between each day, and I also tracked every task in Excel so I'd know for a subsequent playthrough. Without that information, it'd probably be best to build your treasury the first chance you have (although some areas open up after certain tasks are completed).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I regret my few evil decisions just for worrying about treasure. No need at all. Here is what you do: Untill that point of the game save as much money as you can, take your time, don't rush the main story quests, choose all good decisions without heseitation.

The trick is, go to the treasury, take all the money to your personal account. Now, go buy every single bussiness property, or just buy as many as you can. Don't bother the small food vendors etc, just have the buildings. Buy houses and rent them. Set all the prices to highest. (People will hate you for that but it is temporary and ok. You can change the prices back to normal after you collect enough)

Now, while money rolls in all the time, you can go hunt gnomes, silver and gold keys you are missing, explore gold doors, deamon doors,just keep busy with anything you've missed, haven't completed yet. You will have more than enough millions before you will know.

Answer (score -1):

I bought all houses and buisnesses as soon as i possibly could. Then, while doing main story quests and side quests, i got approximatly 20  million dollars and then became king. I then, put all of my money in the treasury and began doing the king decisions and whenever i had money i put it in the treasury. I was making about 150,000$ every 5 minutes.

I hope this helps!!!